# Hibernate Validator @CPF que pode ser nulo

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate, validação

Estou usando o Hibernate Validator com a anotação `@CPF`. Ele está validando beleza, o problema é que meu sistema pode ter o campo do CPF sem valor (nulo) e o Hibernate não aceita isso. Coloquei o campo com `@Collumn (nullable = true)` mas isso não faz efeito sobre o Hibernate.

Comment: Provavelmente não é por conta de versão, mas qual versão do `hibernate-validator` está usando? O `CPFValidator` retorna `true` quando o valor é nulo, não quando é vazio, então é estranho não estar validando quando é nulo. Inclua seu código e o erro (*stacktrace*) pra facilitar na ajuda.

Comment: Consegui solucionar. O problema que o JSF estava passando uma String vazia e não um valor null. Então coloquei no web.xml: <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>

Comment: Legal cara, inclua uma resposta falando que o problema era como o valor chegava para você, ou seja, vazio e não nulo, pode ajudar outras pessoas ;)

Answer (score 2):

O problema era que o JSF estava passando uma String vazia e não um valor `null`. Então coloquei no web.xml:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-n‌​ame>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi da seguinte forma:

```
@CPF
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String cpf;

public void setCpf(String cpf) {
        if(cpf != null && cpf.length() == 0) {
            this.cpf = null;
        }
        else {
            this.cpf = cpf;
        }
    }
```